# std::thread::hardware_concurrency() returns different value in VS debugger

Tags: c++, openmp

If I start the program with the Visual 2015 debugger, it uses all available logical cores (32).
If I start the program without debugger, it uses just 3 cores (6 threads). 
I call `omp_set_num_threads` only once in the program and the output of `qInfo` is in both cases 32. 
I do not use compiler flags to alter the number of threads. Does someone has a quick tip, where in the chain might be the problem?

```
omp_set_num_threads(std::thread::hardware_concurrency());
qInfo() << "Number of threads" << std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
```

Comment: Do you really have a machine with 32 cores?

Comment: 16 physical, 32 logical.

Comment: if you run the release version under visual studio, what do you geT?

Comment: If I start both the debug or the release version in debugger it uses all cores. Just if I start the programs in shell or just by double click it uses a fraction of the available cores. Totally enigmatic :(

Comment: What happens if you set the env variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` before running the program? `omp_set_num_threads` only appears to set an upper limit, it does not force the program to use them. From: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/Runtime-Library-Routines.html#Runtime-Library-Routines

Comment: Still the same behavior

Comment: If the output is the same in both cases, how do you even determine *it uses just 3 cores (6 threads)*. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: You are mixing OpenMP and C++ threads. Just stick to one of them. Use `omp_get_num_procs()` to obtain the number of logical processors.

Comment: I was first trying this. The number the return is the same